# ld: 134 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64 on iOSDevice64 when adding third party framework (AdMob)

Tags: ios, delphi, firemonkey, admob

I downloaded the Google Mobile Ads SDK for iOS and extracted it to the frameworks path of the iOS 11 SDK. I then generated pascal headers for it using the SDK Transform Assistant. I added the headers to an empty project and added the linker options `-ObjC -lz -lsqlite3` to fix "Undefined symbol" errors. I also had to copy over a few other frameworks using the SDK Manager (dependencies of GoogleMobileAds).

The project runs fine on iOSDevice32 but when building for iOSDevice64 linking fails with the error

```
[DCC Error] E2597 duplicate symbol l002 in:
      C:\Users\Christopher Hahn\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\SDKs\iPhoneOS11.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADGestureRecognizer.o)
        C:\Users\Christopher Hahn\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\SDKs\iPhoneOS11.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADNVideoPlayer.o)
  duplicate symbol l002 in:
      C:\Users\Christopher Hahn\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\SDKs\iPhoneOS11.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADGestureRecognizer.o)
        C:\Users\Christopher Hahn\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\SDKs\iPhoneOS11.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADNGLSphericalShader.o)
  duplicate symbol l004 in:
      C:\Users\Christopher Hahn\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\SDKs\iPhoneOS11.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADLocation.o)
        C:\Users\Christopher Hahn\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\SDKs\iPhoneOS11.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADNGLSphericalShader.o)
  duplicate symbol l005 in:
      C:\Users\Christopher Hahn\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\SDKs\iPhoneOS11.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADLocation.o)
        C:\Users\Christopher Hahn\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\SDKs\iPhoneOS11.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADNGLSphericalShader.o)
```

etc.

How can I fix this? I am using Delphi 10.2.3 and XCode 9 on OSX 10.13.6 (although I also tried it with XCode 9.2 and 9.4.1 and the corresponding iOS versions)

Answer (score 0):

It means that you have multiple classes with the same name defined. This could occur when you are using two libraries with the same source.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but aren't the duplicates all from the same library? How would you go about fixing this? (Sorry if I'm wrong, I normally don't deal with iOS libraries)